# File names (from multiple files) as a column names in one data frame

Tags: python, pandas

I have many text files with one column data,different dtype (float64, date), no header inside.
I'm trying to write code which will:
 - get all file names without extension -> create a list (this works!)
 - read all files in one directory and concat them into one data frame with one numerated index.

My code:

```py
filelist = os.listdir(path)                             #Make a file list
file_names=[os.path.splitext(x)[0] for x in filelist]   #Remove file extension
```

Tried this (first option):

```py
df_list = [pd.read_table(file) for file in filelist]
df = pd.concat(df_list,ignore_index=True)
```

...but I got 3 columns from 6 files with completely messed data.

Also tried this (second option):

```py
df=pd.DataFrame(columns=file_names)

for file in filelist:
    frame=pd.read_csv(file)
    df=df.append(frame, ignore_index=True)
```

...this also doesn't work.

Any advice would be appreciated.

**Input**
At the beginning of Q*.txt files are only zeros (about 100values), and after this numbers shows.

```
Q1.txt   Q2.txt   T21     T22
  0       0      51.06    77.46
  0       0      50.32    77.33
  0       0      50.90    77.45
```

When I run "first option", I got:

```py
 filelist
 >>>['Q1.txt', 'Q2.txt','T21.txt', 'T22.txt']     
 file_names
 >>>['Q1', 'Q2','T21', 'T22']
 df.dtypes
 >>>0        object
 >>>51.06    object
 >>>77.46    object
 >>>dtype: object
```

**Output** file

```
    0  51.06 77.46
 0  0       
 1  0       
 2  0
```

It looks like first 2 files (those with zeros at the beginning) are in one column. Second and third are first values of file T21 and T22.

Thanks to @Viktor Kerkez I've added `header=None` to the `pd.read_table` and now all files are in one column, dtype=object.
How can I split all files to many columns ?

Comment: Hi Michal, you are on the right path. I would suggest you check if your individual files have been corectly read into DataFrames. Unfortunately we can't help you further without looking into the files or your error output.

Comment: Can you add a sample of your data files. It looks to me this is something that a few additional parameters to `read_csv` could fix. For example if there is no header, you should probably pass `header=None`

Comment: suggest you check reading in the files on at a time 1st with pd.read_table(file).   make sure it is correct up to that point.   There are lots of paramaters that can be added to read_table if this is the problem step.

Comment: So the files look exactly how you wrote them? Every file has exactly one number per line? And you want a DataFrame that has one column per file?

Comment: @ViktorKerkez exactly as you specified :)

Comment: Are they all the same length? Do they all have the same number of elements? And if not how would you like to fill in the missing values?

Comment: All files should have the same number of elements, if not missing values can be filled with 'NaN'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do the next thing:

```
import os
import pandas as pd

file_names = []
data_frames = []
for filename in os.listdir(path):
    name = os.path.splitext(filename)[0]
    file_names.append(name)
    df = pd.read_csv(filename, header=None)
    df.rename(columns={0: name}, inplace=True)
    data_frames.append(df)

combined = pd.concat(data_frames, axis=1)
```

Here I renamed every DataFrame column to match the file name, you can leave that step out, and just use `ignore_index=True`.